# Orchard Lost Password Email template

Tags: orchardcms, password-recovery, email-templates

I am trying to edit the email template of the lost password functionality of orchard. I can find the view where the default template is generated but when I change it nothing happens because as far as I can understand it is compiled in dll. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what view you're referring to: the message cannot be changed currently without altering Orchard.Users.Handlers.UserMessageAlteration.Sending, unless you replace it with your own implementation and change the message from there.